# MySQL TinyInt Value Won't Update

Tags: php, mysql, tinyint

For the life of me I can't get php to update the schdl field in mysql. It will update EVERY other field in the test queries EXCEPT schdl .

The schdl value is currently set to 1 and I am trying to set it to 0 . The schdl field's NULL option is set to "No" and the Default for the field is "0".

Steps I've taken:
I can execute the below command successfully from MySQL CLI
`UPDATE dispatch SET schdl="0" WHERE servid="12";` <- Again this works fine

But as soon as I try to execute it in PHP, the query comes back as successful but the value remains unchanged.
I've tried:
. I update other values in the same query and they all update as expected, only the schdl remains unchanged. What the heck am I missing?

Is php submitting the '0' value properly and mysql is interpreting the value weirdly and setting it to True or something?

How do I fix this?

PHP 5.4.3
MySQL 5.5.24

Comment: post what u tried in php

Comment: post your php sql query statement

Comment: Are you sure that `$servid2` is equal to `12`? Try to `var_dump` your `$sql2` variable.

Comment: Again all the other values in the record update, so I know it is finding the record.

Comment: Please provide the resultset of `DESCRIBE dispatch`, and also your MySQL and PHP versions.

Comment: In advance I can say that you don't really need to use quotes in MySQL numeric fields.

Comment: Use `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` extension for updating... show us which extension you are using

Comment: Your table looks fine for me. What I would do if I were you (but I'm not you, so you can disagree): remove every quote involving numeric fields, use mysqli or PDO_MySQL (as said by @Amir) (believe us, you better get used to it), change schdl to `ENUM('n','y')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of `schdl=\"0\"`

```
schdl=0
```